# Tensor over division rings

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $D$ be a division ring containing a field $k$ in its center such that $D$ is finite dimensional over $k$. Consider the left $D$-module $D \otimes_{k} V$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional k-vector space and also $V$ has structure of left $D$-module.

Is it true that $dim_{D}(D \otimes_{k} V)=dim_{k}V$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: show that $D\otimes_k (\oplus_{i=1}^n k)\cong \oplus_{i=1}^nD$ as left $D$-modules.